# Saving openCV.js destination image

Tags: javascript, html, opencv, image-processing

In the code below I want to save `dst` in image format or get an URL to show in an image tag.
There is a method `imwrite()` for other languages but I could not find any for **javascript**.

```
    let imgElement = document.getElementById("ImgViewImage"); // img element with ImgViewImage id
    let src = cv.imread(imgElement);
    let dst = new cv.Mat();
    let hsvPlanes = new cv.MatVector();
    let mergedPlanes = new cv.MatVector();
    cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 0);
    cv.split(src, hsvPlanes);
    let H = hsvPlanes.get(0);
    let S = hsvPlanes.get(1);
    let V = hsvPlanes.get(2);
    cv.equalizeHist(V, V);
    mergedPlanes.push_back(H);
    mergedPlanes.push_back(S);
    mergedPlanes.push_back(V);
    cv.merge(mergedPlanes, src);
    cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_HSV2RGB, 0);
    cv.imshow("canvasOutput", dst); // canavas element with canvasOutput id
    src.delete();
    dst.delete();
    hsvPlanes.delete();
    mergedPlanes.delete();
```

In addition, is there any way to give the image source directly to the `src` variable in javascript?